# wp_query and sorting on meta data excludes products with no entries

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `wp_query` and sorting the results with a meta key, the problem is it's excluding products with nothing entered in the column I'm sorting on. I need all the products including ones not rated with top rated at the top.

```
else if($field == "rating" ) {
    $myArgs = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'orderby'          => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'include'          => '',
        'meta_key'         => 'rating',
        'post_type'        => 'job_listing',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'job_listing_region'  => 'London',
        'compare' => ''
    );
}
```

UPDATE: turns out I wsn't getting the sort results I needed, changed the code to the following but the results are still exclusive of non rated products.

```
$myArgs = array(
        'orderby'          => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'post_type'        => 'job_listing',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'job_listing_region'  => "'" . $city . "'",
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'rating',
                'compare' => '<'
            ),
        )
    );
```

Comment: The possible solution would be to save default (empty) meta value with all products.

Comment: The rating is user generated though, I'm assuming there's either an empty space or NULL there in the db as default, probably NULL.

Comment: It might be null there. I can't think of any solution without filling all meta values with empty value by default.

Comment: So there's just no way to include rows w/ blank or NULL in the results?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this-

```
$myArgs = array(
    'post_type'        => 'job_listing',
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'meta_key'         => 'rating',
    'orderby'          => 'meta_value',
    'order'            => 'DESC',        
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'job_listing_region'  => 'London'
);
```